# Why does a simple vec3 color attribute get interpolated in a fragment shader?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm using Three.js, and I found really odd results.

I was just tweaking around, to experiment with attributes, as below

```
const colors = [
      new THREE.Color(0xFF0000),
      new THREE.Color(0x00FF00),
      new THREE.Color(0x0000FF),
      new THREE.Color(0x00FFFF),
    ]
const colorFloats = colors.map(c => c.toArray()).flat();


    const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        color1: {
          value : new THREE.Vector4(1,1,0,1)
        },
        color2: {
          value : new THREE.Vector4(0,1,1,1)
        }
      },
      vertexShader: await vsh.text(),
      fragmentShader: await fsh.text()
    });

    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
    geometry.setAttribute('myColor',
    new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colorFloats, 3))
```

for vertex shader

```
attribute vec3 myColor;
varying vec2 vUvs;
varying vec3 vColor;

void main(){
  vec4 localPosition=vec4(position,1.);
  vColor=myColor;
  gl_Position=projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*localPosition;
}
```

for Fragment. shader

```
varying vec3 vColor;

void main(){
  
  gl_FragColor=vec4(
    vColor,
    1.
  );
}
```

and I got the result shown below:

[image]

I really don't understand why it shows like this.

I just passed 4 Three.js color instances as a bufferArray (which has 12 items [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]

and as far as I know, the shader should take those values as vec3. Shouldn't the result be Vec3(1,0,0), since I'm converting 'myColor' attribute into a 3D vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry has 1 vertex in each corner. The vertex shader runs for each of the 4 vertices, reads the unique color of the vertex, and then writes it to a "varying". When the fragment shader runs, it uses a weighted mix of the varyings from the vertices of that triangle. That's the purpose of GLSL varyings — you can read a longer explanation in https://jameshfisher.com/2017/10/19/glsl-varying/.

In order to have a hard cutoff between colors in the middle of the plane, you'd either need (a) vertices along the dividing line, or (b) more complex fragment shader logic.